# Spring Boot application cannot join Coherence cluster on server: Join request was aborted

Tags: spring-boot, oracle-coherence

I have developed a small REST API application with Spring Boot after another sample application with classic Spring XML configuration. It imports context from a library with a Coherence cache set up.

When I developed it locally, running the Spring Boot app with Intellij Idea runner,  there were no issues, the application worked fine and the endpoint worked connecting to that cache.

When I deployed the application to the Unix server, I am getting the following error during the application startup:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'coreSearchSync' defined in class path resource [core-search-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve  reference to bean 'corePersistenceManager' while setting bean property 'corePersistenceManager';  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with  name 'corePersistenceManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '  coreSearchResultCache' defined in class path resource [core-search-coherence-context.xml]: Bean  instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate  [com.tangosol.net.NamedCache]: Factory method 'getCache' threw exception; nested exception is  (Wrapped: Failed to start Service "Management" (ServiceState=SERVICE_STOPPED)) java.lang.RuntimeException: Join request was aborted`

The application on the server is using the application.properties but they are the same as in the application.yaml locally.

I am not sure where to continue the investigation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by passing JVM arguments to the script to start the application:

`-Dtangosol.coherence.clusterport=<port> -Dtangosol.coherence.site=<site> -Dtangosol.coherence.clusteraddress=<cluster_ip_ddress> -Dtangosol.coherence.cluster=<cluster_name>`

It appears that these properties are not applied from the application properties because starting the coherence cluster works on the system level and/or starts before the properties are initialized. Or those properties are not visible to the coherence.

Comment: You may also want to check out the Coherence Spring project - https://github.com/coherence-community/coherence-spring